# PUT form being sent as POST when hidden field value is modified

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have a form which updates an object, the

`= form_tag (..., method: :put) do`

The HTML will say `method="post"` but the form will be correctly submitted using `PUT`. When I try to change the value of a hidden field based the selection of a button group:

```
  $('#form .btn-group button').click(function(e) {
    $('#form input[type=hidden]').val($(this).data('value'));
  });
```

The form is submitted using `POST`, giving me a 404. I guess I'm breaking something on `jquery_ujs`, but it's been a couple of days and I still have no clue. No JavaScript errors happen and the hidden field value is correctly modified.

Comment: can you check rails log that why it is giving 404 error?

Comment: @codeit the 404 is because no route matches POST /tags/:id. Once the form is submitted with PUT it matches the route for the `update` action.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try changing this `$('#form input[type=hidden]')` to a more precise selector so you don't affect all hidden fields. add a class to the hidden field.  You are most probably overriding all hidden fields which may cause the issue.

Comment: Thanks, I'll be selecting your answer because it was first. I just need to wait 4 minutes.

Answer (score 2):

This is because `method: put` creates a hidden field for the form that looks like:

```
<input name="_method" type="hidden" value="put">
```

Check the `div` that rails inserts immediately below the `form` element.

That's how the application recognizes it as a PUT request rather than POST - by the value of this form parameter. So modifying *all* hidden fields as you do in your js will break the form.

Comment: Thanks for explaining, I have to be more careful with the selectors... I should know by now.